# How to set the pattern conditionally for cols merge in a GT table in R

Tags: r, datatable, gt

I have created a gt table for a dataset with one column being a combination of three columns. It only has values every other row, and I am using the pattern

#### ### (###, ###)

(the octothorps represent real numbers obvi)

the problem I'm having is that it still uses that pattern even when the columns are empty for that row so it will just print (, ) in a cell which I do not want. I just want it to be empty

any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the last version of `gt` (0.9.0) you can now use `<< >>` in the pattern argument of the `cols_merge` function to prevent printing of empty columns. In your case you case you might want to try:

`cols_merge(pattern = "<<{1}<<({2}, {3})>>>>")`

The documentation page for reference: https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/cols_merge.html#how-the-pattern-works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).